# Strange behaviour of jquery selector

Tags: jquery

In the following html code:

```
$('p div').length  //RETURNS 0
```

while

```
$('div a').length //RETURNS 2
```

why?

```
<p>
    <div id="did1">
        <a id='aid1' class="class1">
        one     
         </a>   
        <a id='aid2' class="class2">
        two     
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="did2">
        three
    </div>     
</p>
```

Comment: Divs inside p tags are invalid HTML.

Comment: To extend on what @j08691 said: Because of that, the HTML is not rendered how you think.  It's rendered as `<p></p><div id="did1">..</div><div id="did2">..</div><p></p>`.  That's why the selectors work the way they do.

Comment: @RocketHazmat post as answer this is helpful and answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Lavabeams: Someone beat me to it! :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is rendered as follows:

```
<p></p>
<div id="did1">
    <a id='aid1' class="class1">
    one     
     </a>   
    <a id='aid2' class="class2">
    two     
    </a>
</div>
<div id="did2">
    three
</div>     
<p></p>
```

jQuery does not find any `div` elements inside any `p` elements.